# php textarea, text in tew line

Tags: php, html

```
$city = 'London Paris Lisabona';
```

And i need print this string in textarea.
How print city in new line?
I need in textarea get this:

```
London
Paris
Lisabona
```

Code:

```
$city = 'London\nParis\nLisabona';
echo '<textarea>'.$city.'</textarea>';
```

result:

```
London\nParis\nLisabona
```

Comment: http://php.net/types.string <- read this ca-re-ful-ly

Answer (score 5):

In general: Use `\n` for line breaks.

In your case (only works of cites don't consist of two words, i.e. each word must be a city):

```
$city = str_replace(' ',"\n", $str); // generates 'London\nParis\nLisabona'
```

Or if possible build the string with `\n` instead of spaces from the beginning.

**Update:**

Escaped character sequences like `\n` are only processed in *double* quoted strings. They are taken literally in single quoted strings (with two exceptions). Read more in the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php):

> To specify a literal single quote, escape it with a backslash (`\`). To specify a literal backslash, double it (`\\`). All other instances of backslash will be treated as a literal backslash: this means that the other escape sequences you might be used to, such as `\r` or `\n`, will be output literally as specified rather than having any special meaning.

Thus, you have to declare your strings as

```
$cities = "London\nParis\nLisabona";
```

**Further note:**

Whenever possible avoid echoing HTML with PHP. It makes it more difficult to debug the HTML. Instead, embed the PHP into HTML like so:

```
<?php
    $cities = "London\nParis\nLisabona";
?>
<textarea><?php echo $cities; ?></textarea>
```

Comment: Please NOTE he used double quotes "\n" not single '\n' -- this is very important!

Comment: Thanks, but when i print text i get this:
London\nParis\nLisabona

Comment: @lolalola: Do you print the text in a textarea? It works for me.

Comment: @lolalola: Could you show your code please? Just edit your question and add it.

Comment: @lolalola: You have to declare the string with double quotes: `"London\nParis\nLisabona"`. Escaped characters are not recognized in single quoted strings.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php

$city = "London\nParis\nLisabona";
?>

<textarea rows="3" cols="20">
<?php echo $city; ?>
</textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$city = str_replace(' ', "<br />", $city);
```

If you echo it in HTML.

Answer (score 0):

```
<textarea><?= str_replace(" ", "<br />", $city); ?></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want "\n" to be converted to line breaks, you need to use double-quotes instead of single quotes.

i.e.

```
$foo = 'a\nb\nc\n';
echo $foo;
> a\nb\nc\n

$foo = "a\nb\nc\n";
echo $foo;
> a
> b
> c
```

Answer (score 0):

`&#10;` works in `<textarea>` form me, lines might get soft-wrapped though (but that is expected)